# How do I specifiy maximum field length using .net framework 4.0 and EF Code First?

Tags: winforms, data-annotations, code-first

I am writting a winforms application. I had the domain classes nicely working with Code First and .Net Framework 4.5  however I need to switch to .Net Framework 4.0 so that the application will run on Windows XP.

The version of [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for framework 4.0 does not support the MaxLength data annotation.

What should I do instead?

Update:
The following works
    [StringLength(450, ErrorMessage = "The field cannot exceed 450 characters. ")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following will solve my problem

```
 [StringLength(450, ErrorMessage = "The field cannot exceed 250 characters. ")]
```